# restrict user to select future date in datepicker

Tags: android

I have used `DatePicker` to calculate age from user input birthday date. Now I want to restrict the user to select a future date... here is the code that I have used in `mainActivity.java`

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment                            
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{    
    @Override   
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker        
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
        int mBirthYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
        int mMonthOfYear = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);        
        int mDayOfMonth= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);        
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it       
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mBirthYear,mMonthOfYear ,mDayOfMonth  );

}           


public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int mBirthYear, int mMonthOfYear, int mDayOfMonth) 
{
  int mAge;  
  mAge = Year-mBirthYear;
  if ((mMonthOfYear == Month && Day < mDayOfMonth) || ( Month < mMonthOfYear) )  
         {
                    mAge--;
          }                

                 String years = String.valueOf(mAge);
                  MainActivity.textView6.setText(years);
```

Comment: check the selected date with current date, if it is not a future date restrict and show appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

this is reverse operation. restricting to select expired date.

i don't know any special method for this

but i solved like this, this may be not standard one but works for me

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        final Calendar cf = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cf.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cf.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = cf.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Log.e("year", selectedYear + "year " + year);
        if (selectedYear < year) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please choose future date", 1).show();
        }
        if (selectedMonth < month) {
            if (selectedYear <= year) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please choose future date", 1).show();
            } else {
                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;

                // set selected date into textview
                shipdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));
            }
        }
        if (selectedDay < day) {
            if (selectedMonth <= month) {
                if (selectedYear <= year) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please choose future date", 1).show();

                } else {
                    year = selectedYear;
                    month = selectedMonth;
                    day = selectedDay;

                    // set selected date into textview
                    shipdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-")
                            .append(year).append(" "));
                }

            } else {
                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;

                // set selected date into textview
                shipdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));
            }

        } else {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            shipdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
        }

    }
};
```